# Using Zelig with ggplot2, graphing simulations and models

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-zelig

I am attempting to using `ggplot2` to graph some basic simulations and multi-variable regression models but am at a loss.

I am using `Zelig 3.5` (as newer Zeligs have glitches with simulations)

Based on a blog I found, I tried this

```
AppMod1 <- (s1$qi)
AppMod1 <- data.frame(AppMod1$ev)

AppMod1 <- melt(AppMod1,     measure=1:86)
AppMod1 <- ggplot(AppMod1, aes(approve, year)) +
                 geom_point() +
                 geom_smooth(colour="blue") +
                 theme_tufte()
AppMod1
```

`
This didn't work. I got an error

> "Error: measure variables not found in data:NA"

My models are m1, m2, and m3, and my simulations are m1 and m2. I am using the "approval" data set which comes in Zelig.

The models are calculated as follows

```
data(approval)
m1 <- zelig(approve~avg.price, model="ls", data=approval)
m2 <- zelig(approve~avg.price+sept.oct.2001+iraq.war, model="ls", data=approval)
m3 <- zelig(approve~avg.price+sept.oct.2001+avg.price:sept.oct.2001, model="ls", data=approval)
```

And the simulations are

```
x1 <- setx(m2, sept.oct.2001= 1)
s1 <- sim(m2, x=x1)
summary(s1)

x1 <- setx(m2, sept.oct.2001= 0)
s1 <- sim(m2, x=x1)
summary(s1)

oilprice <- min(approval$avg.price):max(approval$avg.price)
x2 <- setx(m2, sept.oct.2001=0, avg.price=oilprice)
s2 <-sim (m2, x=x2)
plot.ci(s2)

oilprice <- min(approval$avg.price):max(approval$avg.price)
x2 <- setx(m2, sept.oct.2001=1, avg.price=oilprice)
s2 <-sim (m2, x=x2)
plot.ci(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error resulted from your call to `melt`.

Note that in the second line of code `AppMod1 <- data.frame(AppMod1$ev)` you overwrite the assignment you made in your first line of code `AppMod1 <- (s1$qi)`. So after these two lines of code `AppMod1` is equal to a data frame with the single column `ev`.

Now `melt` tries to melt this data frame and the call to `melt` indicates that there are 86 columns of `measure.vars`, when in fact there is only one column in the data frame. That results in the error you described.

I can't quite tell from your code what you're expecting `AppMod1` to look like. When I run your code, `s1$qi` contains only `NULL` values. At the very least, you'll need `AppMod1` to include columns for `approve` and `year` in order for your `ggplot` code to work as written.

Hopefully this is enough information to go on for now. It will be easier to provide additional help if you show what you expect `AppMod1` to look like before and after the call to `melt`.